# Use existing ml.net model to predict using json as model input

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am trying to run a prediction using a previously created model but don't want to have to write code just to be able to run a prediction. I am able to build a model using C# code but then I want to be able to call that new model without writing code to call it specifically.  If I have the path to the .zip file and a record that I know is the same structure model as what was used to train it can't I generically send over json data with matching fields as the model input without having to recompile or write the model code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific as to what you mean by writing code? Do you mean writing code to create input and output schema classes for your model or writing the code that makes the predictions.

### Defining input and output schema classes

If you don't want to create the model schemas, assuming you're using VS2019+ you can leverage the "Paste JSON as Classes" feature.

https://codewithoutcomplaint.com/how-to-generate-a-c-class-from-json-in-visual-studio-2019/

For the output, check out the Tasks documentation which explains the expected outputs depending on the type of model you've built.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/resources/tasks

### Writing consumption code

If you don't want to write code to consume the model, there's not much of a workaround there. The only way that you'd write minimal code to consume your model is using Model Builder which provides starter code for model consumption.

Here's an example of using Model Builder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/predict-prices-with-model-builder#optional-consume-the-model

Comment: Sorry I mean the code to create the input and output schemas.  I want to be able to build a model with sample data and then to run an example record and get a prediction in one command.  Is that not possible? The class generator will help but will still require a manual intervention to run it . Thanks